# How to set the default channel Slack opens up to when you first open the app?

Tags: slack, mac

On MacOS, when I first open Slack, it always opens to a certain channel. Is there a way to set the default?

Comment: What web browser are you using? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].